# What is the value of i which I am assigning to \0?

Tags: c

I am not sure what the value I am assigning to `\0` is here. Here it is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char Str[100], RevStr[100];
    int i, j, len;

    printf("\n Please Enter any String :  ");
    gets(Str);

    j = 0;
    len = strlen(Str);

    for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        RevStr[j++] = Str[i];
    }
```

What is `i` here?? Is it equal to 0 because I'm at the end of the for loop?
I tried setting `RevStr[0] = '\0'` and `RevStr[0] = 'len - 1'` and I got a weird answers.

```
    RevStr[i] = '\0';
```

Also, what does this step do? It seems to format everything well, but I don't understand what it's doing.

```
    printf("\n String after Reversing = %s", RevStr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `RevStr[i] = '\0';` --> `RevStr[j] = '\0';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The value of `i`

After this loop:

```
for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    //...
```

the value of `i` is -1, given that `len` is greater or equal to 0.

The loop repeats as long as its condition is met. The condition is `i >= 0`. When `i` is decremented to 0 the condition is still met and the loop runs another time. At the end `i--` is executed and `i` becomes -1. Now the condition evaluates to `false` and the loop breaks.

If you now execute

```
RevStr[i] = '\0';
```

the character **before** `RevStr` will be overwritten. This is an out-of-bounds access that might destroy any other thing. Behaviour is undefined now, anything can happen, from "nothing" to "the world implodes, at least for the program."

## Where to store '\0'

A string is commonly limited in C by the special character '\0'. It belongs to the end of the string.

After the loop `j` indexes the character **after** the last copied character in `RevStr`. So you can write this to mark the end of the string:

```
RevStr[j] = '\0';
```

The reason why `j` has that value is left as an exercise for you. You might like to insert some `printf()` at strategic places to watch variables, or to learn to use a debugger.

## The formatted output

*Note: I'd like to recommend to read your C lectures once more. Or, in lack of such, look up the description of `printf()`. You should get used to this because you will never learn all details of any programming language. Actually I'm "doing C" since more than 30 years for a life and I still look up details just to make sure I do it right.*

```
printf("\n String after Reversing = %s", RevStr);
```

But for your convenience, here is a short explanation. The first argument to `printf()` is a format string. As long as no '%' is encountered every character is output as given. Now if a '%' is found the next character(s) decide how to proceed. In this case the next character is 's' which means that the next argument is interpreted as a pointer to a string that will be output. So after the blank after the '=' the contents of `RevStr` is output. That's why it is so important that the string is limited by '\0'.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `RevStr[j] = '\0';` because `'\0'` indicates the end of any string.
so `'\0'` must be appended at end of new string (after you've copied all the characters).